# Issues with Google Drive REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, google-drive-api, salesforce, apex

I am building an integration between Google and Salesforce, for this I am APEX. Due to the flow and the way Salesforce works, I have had to create a Service Account and log in using this.

I am now having an issue; I log in: all is well, I then make a second callout to try and get the 2 most recent created records in my Drive: I only receive 1 file - the PDF with the Welcome text and info on how to use the Drive...

So I did a bit of testing and found the following:

1. If I use [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) and Authenticate using OAuth 2.0 I don't get any issues and I am able to get all of the documents that I want to get.
2. If I get an Access Token and append it to this URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxx I get a reply letting me know that my token is correct and that I have the correct scope needed (see below)

   ```js
   {
    "issued_to": "1234567890",
    "audience": "1234567890",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts",
    "expires_in": 3493,
    "access_type": "offline"
   }
   ```

Does anyone have any ideas of what I could be doing wrong? I used a service account to be able to start the initial connection for whom I have activated "Enable Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation", I have also set as many permissions as possible to enable the user the ability to basically view and modify **everything**

**--------Update--------**

Code Snippets

Method to build callout:

```
public void getRecentImages(){
    Integration_Settings__c settings = Integration_Settings__c.getValues('Google APIs');

    String endpoint = settings.Endpoint_URL__c + '/drive/v3/files' +
        '?corpus=user' +
        '&orderBy=createdTime' +
        '&pageSize=2';

    Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
    headers.put('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    headers.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.put('Charset', 'UTF-8');

    String method = 'GET';

    HttpResponse res = doCallout(endpoint, method, null, headers);

    System.debug(res.getBody());

    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());

    // New instance of GoogleFiles
    Google.GoogleFiles response;

    // Try/Catch
    try {
        // Parse JSON into response
        response = (Google.GoogleFiles)parser.readValueAs(Google.GoogleFiles.class);

        System.debug(response);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.debug(e.getLineNumber() + ' - ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Method to do callout:

```
public HttpResponse doCallout(String endpoint, String method, String body, Map<String, String> headers){
    // Instataite new instance of Http
    Http h = new Http();

    // Instatiate new instace of HttpRequest
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    // Set Endpoint URL
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);

    // Set Method Type
    req.setMethod(method);

    // Set Body
    if(body != null)
        req.setBody(body);

    // If there are headers set Headers
    if(headers != null && headers.size() > 0)
        for(String s : headers.keySet())
            req.setHeader(s, headers.get(s));

    // Return HttpResponse
    return h.send(req);
}
```

**--------Update 2--------**

JSON that is returned in the Salesforce and PostMan callout:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "files": [
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "0B_07cXloqOyRc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl",
      "name": "Getting started",
      "mimeType": "application/pdf"
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON that is returned from https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "nextPageToken": "xxxxxx",
  "files": [
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "0B34hDNHXoLmVTFZ1VXhzbHRkUmc",
      "name": "Osney Media - 00038156",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    },
    {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "xxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    },
    ETC......
  ]
}
```

Comment: You mentioned: "I then make a second callout to try and get the 2 most recent created records in my Drive". Please elaborate how you actually did that. Please share the code block.

Comment: @some1 code added!

Comment: First, you can only use the [scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need) `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, it already have full permission to access the files. If you are using the Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority, then it is correct to delegate this authority by using the service account. So I suggest to double check if you follow the proper steps in creating [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Comment: @KENdi, I followed the "Creating a service account" instructions as well as Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account and I am still getting the same 1 record returned in the callout, I have tried changing corpus from user to domain also, but still nothing more :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to update the sharing rules for the relevant folders to share the content with the Service account... a stupid way to do it as it should have org wide delegation... but that's life.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the 2 most **recent** created documents, you will need to have **&orderBy=createdTime%20desc** instead.

Without *%20desc*, you will get the very first 2 documents created.

By the way, you may want to include additional search parameters with **&q=....** to filter off other unwanted files, e.g. only list those created under a certain folders or owned by certain users, and probably also **trashed%3Dfalse**

Comment: Thanks for this comment! My problem is, even without these filters - it won't return anything... only the Getting started document is returned. No other docs are returned... I even created a new Google Doc yesterday to test and it wasn't returned.

Comment: I have added in the JSON response from both the Google callout and Salesforce/PostMan callouts.

Comment: How did you create the new Google Doc, is that being shared with the Service Account?

Comment: I created it from within the Google Drive with the Google Account that is making the callouts.

Comment: If the Google Doc has been created interactively in Google Drive and has not  been shared with the Service Account, the only way to access it via API with Service Account is to have the OAuth process to impersonate the interactive user. Not sure if you have done that correctly.

Comment: I can't believe it... I had to manually share all Folders with the Service account -_- I thought the whole point of setting permissions for the Service account was that you did not have to actually do this :/

Comment: you may first create a folder and configure the sharing, then anything added to that folder interactively will inherit the sharing permission by default. As far as what I understand, Service Account is just another account in term of permission, the only differences are 1) it uses private keys instead of password, 2) it has capability to impersonate as a different account if the "Domain-wide Delegation" is granted correctly.